# сохранить веб страницу в jpg посредством php

Tags: php, веб-программирование, jpeg

Как можно сделать скриншот веб страницы на сайте в jpg посредством php в файл с именем 1.jpg, в папку на сайте например /var/www/1/, и если он существует то перезаписать.

Comment: вы путаете СО с фриланс.ру ... конкретнее вопрос задайте.

Comment: Откорректировал

Comment: речь идёт не о том что бы задчу поставиить, а о том что нужно самому попытаться и если что то неполучилось выложить код. Если вам нужно какое то решение, но вы не знаете php то вам к фрилансерам, а не на stackoverflow сдесь не решают бесплатно поставленые задачи, сдесь программисты помогаю программистом. Это обучающий ресурс а не ресурс фриланса.

Comment: В том и вопрос, я перерыл весь гугл и не смог найти ничего подобного. Поэтому и спросил тут

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Есть сервис [s-shot](https://www.s-shot.ru/), который позволяет делать скриншоты страних по URL.

Вам нужно забрать картинку по адресу и сохранить в нужную папку.

Так же на этом сервисе есть возможность например добавлять get параметр, который не будет влиять на вид страницы например с датой временем а сервис будет воспринимать это как другую страницу, а вы будете иметь актуальный скриншот

[Пример изображения](http://mini.s-shot.ru/1920/1920/jpg/?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546857/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B2-jpg-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-php)

Comment: У них кэширование отключается только после оплаты. А мне нужно делать скриншоты раз в сутки. Видимо не подойдет. Нашел еще похожие сервисы только которые ставятся на локальный сервер. Но никак не могу с ними разобраться. Вроде для Linux но в нутри почему-то есть файл exe.

Comment: Есть возможность например добавлять get параметр, который не будет влиять на вид страницы например с датой временем — сервис будет воспринимать это как другую страницу, а вы будете иметь актуальный скриншот. [Например](http://mini.s-shot.ru/1920/1920/jpg/?http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546857/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B2-jpg-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-php?1)

Answer (score -1):

по средством php ни как потума как необходимо реализвать одну чтуку:

1. браузер который будет парсить и рендерить разметку страницы в графический буфер а после выгружать в  картинку

легче взять готовые решения на друггих языках к примеру руби, запускать браузер делать скрин и выгружать в картинку.

Comment: Понял спасибо..

Comment: Не совсем верно. Можно использовать сервисы, которое это умеют делать